# Delete from a table after a lookup on another table - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hiii
I have two tables

`Invited`

- UID [pk]

`Active`

- UID [pk]

I want to delete UID from `Invited` who is present in `Active` table
Can i do this with Joining or the only approach is to use `NOT IN or IN` ?

Comment: My suggestion to you is to rethink your schema.  A UID should be unique for a single record in a database yet you have two tables that both have the same UID as their primary key.  You are defeating the purpose of UID by doing this.

Comment: @maple_shaft: UID in each case could actually be a foreign key, which just happened to be the primary key as well.

Comment: Yes and this is still wrong.  The reason one would use a UID is to uniquely identify a single record across not just the schema but ALL databases.  This is different from just ID where it is unique to a single table Eg. (TableCar ID - 23 Name - Mercedes, TableDriver ID - 23 Name - Joe)  both tables are unique on ID and both have a value of 23 but they represent different records.  Further ID of 23 in a different database with the same schema would still represent different records even in the same tables.

Comment: @maple_shaft: you are jumping to all kinds of conclusions based on scant information. I agree with @Andriy M: there is every reason to believe there is a third table that the two both reference i.e. two 1:0..1 relationships.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use `IN`.

`Delete From Invited where UID in (Select UID From Active)`

Or you can use a Join if you want to

```
Delete i
From Invited as i
Join Active as a on i.UID = a.UID
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DELETE FROM `Invited` WHERE Invited.UID IN ( SELECT UID FROM `Active`)
```

or, for a performance improvement:

```
DELETE i FROM `Invited` AS i WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM `Active` WHERE Active.UID = i.UID )
```